# django: how to add photo field to the User: User() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: django

I have extended the User to have one more field profile_image, however, when I try to register and upload the image I'm getting an error:

```
User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'profile_image'
```

views-register form>

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # Get form values
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        password2 = request.POST['password2']
        profile_image = request.POST['profile_image']

        # Check if passwords match
        if password == password2:
            # Check username
            if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.error(request, 'Username exists')
                return redirect('register')
            else:
                if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    messages.error(request, "Email exists")
                    return redirect('register')  
                else:
                    # if ok
                    user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email, first_name = first_name, last_name = last_name,profile_image=profile_image)
                # Login after register
                auth.login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, "You are now logged in." )
                user.save()
                return redirect('dashboard')
    else:
        return render(request, 'pages/register.html')
```

models>extended Profile

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'profiles/%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True, null = True)
```

How can I add photo_image to the User? Any help is appreciated!

**UPDATE**: The profile_image is successfully added to the Profile, however, the path is different.

The right way:

```
Currently: profiles/2021/02/06/me_fITbPm2.png
```

This is how it is saved:

```
Currently: me.png
```

How can I change the path? :(

```
            # if ok
            user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password, email=email, first_name = first_name, last_name = last_name)
            custom_user = Profile.objects.create(user = user,profile_image=profile_image)
        # Login after register
        auth.login(request, user)
        messages.success(request, "You are now logged in." )
        custom_user.save()
        return redirect('dashboard')
```

**SOLVED**
With little tricks its working now. I'm posting the solution just in case someone else needed

```
            todayT = datetime.now()
            today_path = todayT.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
            custom_user = Profile.objects.create(user = user, profile_image= 'profiles/'+today_path+'/'+profile_image)
```

Comment: User model does not have profile_image, Profile does

Comment: I fix that one, but I have another issue with the image path. It's not saving the image where it supposes.